# Right-click without touch-to-click

Tags: gnome, touchpad

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 and GNOME 3 on a Dell Precision 5520. I am not using the synaptics driver because it's way too sensitive, just using the vanilla xinput. I disabled tap-to-click (still too sensitive) and am wondering how to right click. Ideally, I'd like to be able to hold super and click or something, like control+click on the Mac, but clicking on the right side of the pad or holding the click would be OK too.

I found the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, but that's a three-key two-hand kind of deal on this laptop (have to hold <kbd>Fn</kbd> to get <kbd>F10</kbd> to be <kbd>F10</kbd> and not a keyboard brightness switcher) so it's not very easy to enact. I'm looking for other options or a way to configure this.

I have poked around in xinput, Tweaks and dconf-editor and don't see anything relevant to this.

Comment: If you wish, you can change (swap) the function key behaviour from BIOS I believe (i.e. Fn+F10 will change brightness instead of F10).

Comment: In fact (on mine at least) fn-escape acts as "fn lock".